# Use serilog's loggingLevelSwitch globally under Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, dependency-injection, serilog

I use serilog for logging in an asp.net framework. I would like to be able to change the log level dynamically through an api. I create a LoggingLevelSwitch object and give it to the logger configuration in the Program.cs as follows

```
LoggingLevelSwitch loggingLevelSwitch = new()

public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IConfigurationRoot configuration = ...

            LoggingLevelSwitch loggingLevelSwitch = new();

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration)
                .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(loggingLevelSwitch)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .CreateLogger();

            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();

            Log.CloseAndFlush();
        }

    ...

    }
```

Now the problem is that the loggingLevelSwitch object is not globally available. I could, of course, make the variable public static, however I would prefer to use dependency injection to have the object be globally available that way. This is problematic, however, because in the main of Program.cs the interfaces and their implementations are not registered yet.

---

I would like to have a class LevelChanger.cs with a constructor like this

```
        public LevelChanger()
        {
            loggingLevelSwitch = new LoggingLevelSwitch();

        }
```

that allows access to the logging level switch. In an ugly workaround I made the loggingLevelSwitch public static (as mentioned above) and changed the constructor of the LevelChanger to be:

```
        public LevelChanger()
        {
            loggingLevelSwitch = Program.loggingLevelSwitch;

        }
```

while adding the LevelChanger as a singleton in the ConfigureServices function

```
            s.AddSingleton<ILevelChanger, LevelChanger>();
```

It felt filthy doing this. But hey, functionally, it does exactly what I want. Still, I tried getting rid of the public static, by configuring the Logger in the Configure() method of Startup.cs, as at this point, the Dependency Injection Container should be ready.

```
public void Configure(..., ILevelChanger levelChanger)
        {

            ...

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(appConfiguration)
                .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(levelChanger.GetLoggingLevelSwitch())
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .CreateLogger();

            ...
        }
```

Now for the final twist, this works, *but* within the appsettings.json, I enriched the logs using Span

```
"Serilog": {
        "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Console" ],
        "MinimumLevel": {
            "Default": "Information",
            "Override": {
                "Microsoft": "Warning",
                "System": "Warning"
            }
        },
        "Enrich": [ "WithSpan", "FromLogContext" ],
        "WriteTo": [
            {
                "Name": "Console",
                ...
            }
        ]
    }
```

This used to add in particular the TraceID to the log. However, now the TraceID, previously supplied by enriching with span, does not appear anymore!

---

Essentially my question is, how should I *actually* get access to the loggingLevelSwitch in my scenario.